# How can I find reporters who wrote at least one articles using django orm?

Tags: python, django

below are models:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('headline',)
```

How can I find reporters who wrote at least one articles using Django orm?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter reporters using [isnull](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
Reporter.objects.filter(article__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: Ohh nice then. Here's an +1 for reverse querying.

Comment: @刘胜朋  My code return all reporters who wrote at least one article. I thought this is exactly what you want `How can I find reporters who wrote at least one articles using Django orm?` Nevertheless you are right if you need to select those authors who wrote more then two articles you need something else.